# In handling two 1/2-spin particles, why is there only one singlet state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

Why is $\left|\uparrow\uparrow\right\rangle +\left|\downarrow\downarrow\right\rangle$ not discussed, despite having a total spin s = 0?

Comment: You've just calculated the z-component. What about <S^x>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it *doesn't* have total spin $s=0$ - it has total spin $s=1$, with the spin component parallel to the $z$-axis being zero.  If you looked at that state in a different basis (e.g. the $x-$ or $y-$ basis) it would very clearly not have spin 0.

Comment: In that case, why is  ∣↑↑⟩+∣↓↓⟩ not considered as part of the s = 1 triple state?

Comment: @allidoiswin It is!  The triplet *space* is not just a set of three vectors, it's an entire vector space - the eigenspace of the ${\bf S} \cdot {\bf S}$ operator with eigenvalue $s(s+1)$ for $s = 1$.  So that state is *a* triplet state.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a picture can help. Its not hugely rigorous (especially for a physics site) but using the vector model, pictures can be constructed to illustrate the states that two spins $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can form.[image: spins]